# Loading classpath resources that reside at the ear level

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath, ear

I have a resource defined at the ear level, such as {ear}/META-INF/somefile.txt.

I would like to load that file from a war in that ear using classpath resources (`getResourceAsStream`). I assume you can not do this, but wanted to check if there was a way to do that that i was unaware of.

Comment: You can put the file into a jar. Register that .jar as java module in the application.xml of the ear. A plain .txt will not work with standard ears, but there might be some as specific extensions that allow it.

Comment: You should mention if you would like necessary a "standard" way or something working on a given AS and if so you should add a tag to specify the AS

Comment: the file has to be were it is for the application server. I guess i'll just build-step copy it into the war, and get it that way. thanks!